Unable to create and push iceberg tables to S3
I am currently working on a small setup where I have an EKS cluster and a Postgresql on RDS. I have created a separate namespace in my eks and named it "new-trino". Inside this namespace I have created a service account, an iceberg rest deployment and a trino setup.
My goal is to create iceberg tables using the postgres data and push it to s3.
The configs are as show below:
service-account.yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: ServiceAccount
metadata:
  name: trino-service-account
  namespace: new-trino
  annotations:
    eks.amazonaws.com/role-arn: "arn:aws:iam::385346727387:role/EKS-Trino-Iceberg-Access"


iceberg-rest.yaml
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: iceberg-rest
  namespace: new-trino
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: iceberg-rest
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: iceberg-rest
    spec:
      serviceAccountName: trino-service-account
      containers:
      - name: iceberg-rest
        image: tabulario/iceberg-rest:0.6.0
        ports:
        - containerPort: 8181
        env:
        - name: AWS_REGION
          value: "us-west-2"
        - name: CATALOG_WAREHOUSE
          value: "s3://my-iceberg-bucket/iceberg-warehouse"
        - name: AWS_WEB_IDENTITY_TOKEN_FILE
          value: "/var/run/secrets/eks.amazonaws.com/serviceaccount/token"
        - name: AWS_ROLE_ARN
          value: "arn:aws:iam::3385346727387::role/EKS-Trino-Iceberg-Access"
        volumeMounts:
        - name: aws-iam-token
          mountPath: /var/run/secrets/eks.amazonaws.com/serviceaccount
          readOnly: true
        resources:
          limits:
            memory: "2Gi"
            cpu: "1"
          requests:
            memory: "1Gi"
            cpu: "500m"
      volumes:
      - name: aws-iam-token
        projected:
          sources:
          - serviceAccountToken:
              audience: "sts.amazonaws.com"
              expirationSeconds: 86400
              path: token
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: iceberg-rest
  namespace: new-trino
spec:
  selector:
    app: iceberg-rest
  ports:
  - port: 8181
    targetPort: 8181
  type: ClusterIP



trino-values.yaml
image:
  tag: "463"
  pullPolicy: IfNotPresent
server:
  workers: 2
  config:
    properties:
      "iceberg.s3.endpoint": "s3.us-west-2.amazonaws.com"
      "iceberg.s3.region": "us-west-2"
      "iceberg.aws.credentials-provider": "InstanceProfile"
      "iceberg.fs.s3.path-style-access": "true"
serviceAccount:
  create: false
  name: trino-service-account
coordinator:
  service:
    type: LoadBalancer
    port: 8080
  jvm:
    maxHeapSize: "3G"
  resources:
    limits:
      memory: "4Gi"
      cpu: "2"
    requests:
      memory: "2Gi"
      cpu: "1"
worker:
  jvm:
    maxHeapSize: "3G"
  resources:
    limits:
      memory: "4Gi"
      cpu: "2"
    requests:
      memory: "2Gi"
      cpu: "1"
additionalExchangeManagerProperties:
  - exchange.s3.region=us-west-2
  - exchange.s3.endpoint=s3.us-west-2.amazonaws.com
  
catalogs:
  postgresql: |-
    connector.name=postgresql
    connection-url=jdbc:postgresql://mit-read-replica.c7battky0i8b.us-west-2.rds.amazonaws.com:5432/dev
    connection-user=user
    connection-password=password
  iceberg: |-
    connector.name=iceberg
    iceberg.catalog.type=rest
    iceberg.rest-catalog.uri=http://iceberg-rest.new-trino.svc.cluster.local:8181
    iceberg.file-format=PARQUET
    iceberg.compression-codec=SNAPPY



My containers are working okay and I am able to access the trino CLI. However, if I try to create and iceberg table and push it to s3, I get the following error
"Query 20241106_101839_00010_ue4ps failed: No factory for location: s3://my-trino-bucket/iceberg-warehouse/test/change_log_simple"
trino> SHOW SCHEMAS IN postgresql;
       Schema       
--------------------
 audit              
 information_schema 
 mit                
 pg_catalog         
 public             
 staging            
(6 rows)

Query 20241106_100418_00006_ue4ps, FINISHED, 3 nodes
Splits: 8 total, 8 done (100.00%)
0.19 [6 rows, 79B] [32 rows/s, 427B/s]

trino> CREATE TABLE iceberg.test.change_log_simple (
    ->     id integer,
    ->     organization_id integer,
    ->     change_date timestamp,
    ->     resource_type varchar,
    ->     severity varchar
    -> ) WITH (
    ->     format = 'PARQUET',
    ->     partitioning = ARRAY['year(change_date)'], 
    ->     location = 's3://my-iceberg-trino-bucket/iceberg-warehouse/test/change_log_simple'
    -> );
Query 20241106_104052_00012_ue4ps failed: No factory for location: s3://my-iceberg-trino-bucket/iceberg-warehouse/test/change_log_simple

I have created a vpc endpoint with right vpc & routing table. Also, my EKS-Trino-Iceberg-Access IAM role has full access to my-iceberg-trino-bucket
My trusted entities snippet is as follows:
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "Federated": "arn:aws:iam::12345678:oidc-provider/oidc.eks.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/id/C7EDBFBFC7F70E4FE"
            },
            "Action": "sts:AssumeRoleWithWebIdentity",
            "Condition": {
                "StringEquals": {
                    "oidc.eks.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/id/C7EDBFBFC7F70E4FE:sub": "system:serviceaccount:new-trino:trino-service-account"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}


I created a dummy pod to test my connection with s3 and it was fine
kubectl exec -it s3-test-pod -n new-trino -- bash

bash-4.2# yum install -y aws-cli

Complete!
bash-4.2# aws --version
aws-cli/1.18.147 Python/2.7.18 Linux/5.10.225-213.878.amzn2.x86_64 botocore/1.18.6
bash-4.2# aws s3 ls s3://my-iceberg-bucket/ --region us-west-2
                           PRE iceberg-warehouse/


I am not able to understand where exactly going wrong. Any help/advice/suggestion would be appreciated! Thanks!

Isn't your problem related to the missing connection option:
fs.native-s3.enabled=true?
